# How to avoid LDAP injection in .NET-Core 2.0 using System.DirectoryServices

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ldap, .net-core

With the preview versions of System.DirectoryServices and System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement being available for .NET Core it is possible again to use the LDAP interaction classes e.g. for Active Directory.
What I'm missing is a class like Microsoft.Security.Application.Encoder from .NET Framework 4, which provided LDAP encoding functionality to avoid LDAP injection:

- LdapEncode() (deprecated)
- LdapFilterEncode()
- LdapDistinguishedNameEncode()

I've found a few Encoder classes for Web based use cases like HtmlEncoding, ScriptEncoding or AttributeEncoding, but I can't find one that does the same for LDAP queries.

Is there such a built in class that I just can't find or is there another way to achieve this using other encoders? I guess writing my own would be a bad idea, so I hope that I'm just not good at finding this thing.

Thanks

Comment: Isn't the purpose of .NetCore to work universally on multiple platforms? Isn't Active Directory only for Windows?

Comment: @johnny5, asp.net core targeting .net core is significantly faster than asp.net targeting the full windows .net. If performance is a concern, leveraging asp.net core might be a reasonable option.

Comment: Aren't those encoders part of the NuGet package https://www.nuget.org/packages/AntiXSS/ ? So these functions were never part of .net framework but are in a library (which may even work on .net core 2.0 due to the .net framework compatibility shims)

Comment: @Martin Ullrich Your comment lead me to the right answer. I checked AntiXSS and it was deprecated, instead the class I mentioned in the starting post should be used according to the intellisense comment. I was just using the wrong Encoder class... Microsoft.Security.Application.Encoder should be used and actually is usable.